# Cannot build Archive for a SwiftUI app that uses a XCFramework

Tags: ios, swift, xcframework

My SwiftUI app uses a third-party framework `Foo` (written in objc) that is built into a XCFramework. I can build and run this app in iOS simulator and an iPhone connected to my Mac. But when I do "Product" -> "Archive", it fails with the error:

`Cannot find 'Foo' in scope`

The error is reported at anywhere that uses things like `Foo.bar()`.

Why would Archive fail while both simulator and real device works with the framework? Does Archive try to build the app for some extra platforms?

XCode version: 14.2

I used "Embed & Sign" when importing the framework.

Comment: try clean build or try to check if deployment version for all frameworks are same as you app deployment version

Comment: I tried the menu item "Product" -> "Clean Build Folder",  it did not fix the issue. What do you mean by "deployment version for all frameworks" ? Is there a way to check it?  Btw, the framework Foo is "Cronet" in chromium, built via its build tools, not in a regular Xcode proj.

Comment: is that pod installed framework

Comment: The framework is not pod installed.  It is built into a framework folder `Cronet.framework` for different platforms (e.g. Debug-iphonesimulator, Release-iphoneos). Then I ran `xcodebuild` to create XCFramework to bundle different platform versions into a single XCFramework.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the root cause: In `Build Setting` for the target, I missed setting `Objective-C Bridging Header` for `Release`.

The reason that the build worked for both the simulator and the device is that both of them are running the app in Debug mode, not in Release mode. But Archive requires building in Release mode.

Now I've added the bridging header in the Build Setting for Release mode and the issue is gone.